# How do I find package URLs with Yum?

Tags: fedora, yum, pacman, aria2

I want to update my system (Fedora) with Yum, but I want to use `aria2` to download the packages. There was something in `pacman` that you could use to get the update URLs (and put all links in a file.) Then, `aria2` could use this file as an input list for download. What is the Fedora equivalent?

Answer (score 35):

Use `yumdownloader`. It's in the `yum-utils` package.

To get URLs for packages:

```
yumdownloader --urls mariadb-server
```

To actually download a package and all its dependencies:

```
yumdownloader --resolve mariadb-server
```

You don't really need aria2 at all.