# Installing RPM with Dependencies Offline

Tags: centos, rpm

I am trying to install some packages on a server that has no internet connectivity.

From what I read at [How to use yum to get all RPMs required, for offline use?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/259640/how-to-use-yum-to-get-all-rpms-required-for-offline-use) I should be able to use yumdownloader to download all dependencies using a server with connectivity and copy it for installation elsewhere.

My question is whether this will work on a different Centos minor (6.5 & 6.8) or major (6.8 & 7.0) versions? E.g. Using yumdownload on 6.5, copying the files to 6.8 and installing them.

Thanks!

Comment: A [manpage for `yumdownloader`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/yumdownloader) I found says it has a `--urls` option. If this is the case, you could try playing with this on the disconnected system to generate a list of files to fetch using the system with an Internet connection (perhaps using `cURL` or `wget`).

Answer (score 1):

> E.g. Using yumdownload on 6.5, copying the files to 6.8 and installing them

This should be ok, although I'd suggest to use the same major.minor version if possible. On the other hand, doing this on different major versions (e.g. downloading the files on CentOS 7 and installing on CentOS 6) will surely **not** work as the list of packages and dependencies is different.

Answer (score 0):

I would agree with the first solution, but to install some kernel modules like DRBD etc., they would need to be re-complied to your Cent OS kernel version.