# Installing Apache HTTPD RPM on an offline RHEL 7.2 server

Tags: rhel, apache-httpd, rpm

I need to install `httpd` on an offline RHEL 7.2 box, which means no `yum`.

I read somewhere that `httpd` comes natively as part of RHEL 7.2, but I can't find it anywhere within the server.

Is there any way I can get an `RPM` package for installation? Since the box is offline, I can't use yum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you can download dependencies on different host and copy them to your offline host. Remember that installing `httpd`, means installing `httpd` and dependencies. You have a similar questions here: [[1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/259640/how-to-use-yum-to-get-all-rpms-required-for-offline-use)], [[2](https://serverfault.com/questions/693546/how-to-install-packages-offline)].