# Problems getting YUM to see packages is local repository

Tags: yum, repository

I've downloaded all the rpms and created a local repository for offline installation of php 5.6 by following the instructions of Steve Bond's solution mentioned [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/259640/how-to-use-yum-to-get-all-rpms-required-for-offline-use/260261#260261) using 'downloadonly' and create repo. The problem that I am running into is that when I copy this to the offline server and run 'yum install' it tells me that there are dependencies missing (is. libssl, pce, etc.) However, when I look in the actual local repository I can see all of these packages in there. How can I force yum to find the dependencies in that repository as well? shouldn't it be doing that by default?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Reading through Mr Bond's solution, I noticed that by default he has his local repository disabled.  He then manually enables the repo on the command line.  If you set up your repo similarly, you can fix your problem one of two ways:

- By setting `enabled=1` in your .repo file
- By adding `--enablerepo=myrepo` to your yum command line

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I had noticed that previously as well

Answer (score 0):

for some reason the "repoclosure --repoid=offline-php" command in Steve's post was not running properly to check for all dependencies in the listed packages inside the director. It was reading 0 packages. I started over again and go it to work.