# is there an alternative to numlockx for RHEL 7.6?

Tags: rhel, dependencies, numlock

I'm setting up an offline RHEL 7.6 workstation (no network allowed, ever) and identifying all of the dependencies involved in using numlockx is becoming ridiculous. I'm trying to find out whether RHEL 7.6 provides the capability without needing the numlockx rpm.

Comment: By downloading RHEL you have connected it (indirectly) to the internet. What is your reason for no network? (You may have not complied with the intent of the rule.)

Comment: Does `rpm` have a `--download-only` (as found in `apt`). It can be used to download the dependencies on another machine.

Comment: Related: [How to use yum to get all RPMs required, for offline use?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/259640/how-to-use-yum-to-get-all-rpms-required-for-offline-use)

Comment: Actually I have used a Windows 10 system to download the installation DVD and burn it. The reason for not using any network is security.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this Red Hat KB](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/175133), `setleds` in the `kbd` package will do it, with:

```
setleds +num
```

or

```
setleds -num
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the best solution in another thread: [Offline RPM Package Install With Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/1322427/offline-rpm-package-install-with-windows).  I set up a RHEL 7.6 VM, from which I can use yum to download all the required RPMs and move them to the isolated workstation.